# How to know if a Feynman diagram is planar?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, topology, large-n

A *planar* diagram is defined as being one of the leading diagrams for $N \to \infty$ (large $N$ expansion), and, as I understand it, it should have the lowest genus when compared to a *non-planar* diagram. It is of course very useful to be able to distinguish planar from non-planar just by looking at the diagram without having to compute color factors every time.

To illustrate my misunderstanding, let us consider the two following diagrams:

[image]

Here the circles top and bottom correspond to trace, i.e. these diagrams represent a two-point function with composite operators of the form:

$$\mathcal{O}_k (x) \propto \text{Tr}\ T^{a_1} T^{a_2} T^{a_3} T^{a_4} \phi^{a_1} \phi^{a_2} \phi^{a_3} \phi^{a_4}, \tag{1}$$

with the $a$'s corresponding to color indices and the $\phi$'s are scalar fields.

I would expect diagram $(2)$ to be non-planar, however when I do the computation for each of them I find that both diagrams have the same planarity, since:

$$\begin{align} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b T^c T^d\ \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b T^c T^d & = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b T^c T^a T^b T^c \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b\ \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b \\ & = \frac{1}{8} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^a \\ &= \frac{N^2}{16}, \end{align} \tag{2.a}$$

and

$$\begin{align} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b T^c T^d\ \text{Tr}\ T^b T^a T^c T^d & = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b T^c T^b T^a T^c \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b\ \text{Tr}\ T^b T^a \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b\ \text{Tr}\ T^a T^b \\ &= \frac{N^2}{16}, \end{align} \tag{2.b}$$

where I made heavy use of the following identities:

$$\text{Tr}\ T^a A\ \text{Tr}\ T^a B = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\ A B, \tag{3.a}$$

$$\text{Tr}\ T^a A T^a B = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\ A\ \text{Tr}\ B. \tag{3.b}$$

Is that right? If yes, how can I distinguish planarity diagrammatically then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning OP's diagram (1) & (2) and OP's calculations, note that the labelling of the second vertex is reversed, i.e. the color factor becomes

$$  {\rm Tr}(T^a T^b T^c T^d) {\rm Tr}(T^d T^c T^b T^a)~\stackrel{(3.a')+(3.b')}{=}~({\rm Tr}\mathbb{1})^4+\text{subleading terms}, \tag{2.a'}$$

and

$$  {\rm Tr}(T^a T^b T^c T^d) {\rm Tr}(T^d T^c T^{\color{red}{a}} T^{\color{red}{b}})~\stackrel{(3.a')+(3.b')}{=}~({\rm Tr}\mathbb{1})^3 +\text{subleading terms},\tag{2.b'}$$
respectively. We see that diagram (2) has less index contractions [i.e. factors of ${\rm Tr}\mathbb{1}=N$], which is a hallmark of a [non-planar diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion).

Here we have repeatedly used the formulas
$${\rm Tr}( T^a A) {\rm Tr}( T^a B)~=~ {\rm Tr}(A B)+ \text{subleading terms}, \tag{3.a'}$$

and

$${\rm Tr}(  T^a A T^a B) ~=~   {\rm Tr}(A){\rm Tr}(B)+\text{subleading terms}. \tag{3.b'}$$

References:

1. D. Tong, [Gauge theory lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html); chapter 6.

Answer (score 3):

There is celebrated formula for **Euler characteristic** $$\boxed{\chi = V - E + F}$$  where $V$ is number of vertices, $E$ - number of edges, $F$ - number of faces involved in the graph. The Euler  characteristic is related to the genus $g$ of surface by $\chi = 2 - 2g$. The planar graph corresponds to sphere with $g= 0$.

For the graph (1) you have 2 vertices, 4 edges, 4 faces (exterior face has be taken also into account) - therefore, it is a planar graph. For the graph (2) there seem to be 2 faces, so this graph can be put only on torus, or higher genus surface.

Comment: Right, but this does not address the question fully. When I compute the color factors explicitly the graph $(2)$ seems to be planar. Why is that?

Comment: @Jxx because it *is* planar?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov See the answer by Qmechanic.